# How do I launch an android AVD thats not in the default location?

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator

I have an AVD in a `~/development/app/test/android` folder:

```
~/development/app/test/android/Test1.ini
~/development/app/test/android/Test1.avd
```

How can I launch this without moving them into `~/.android/avd`?

I've tried adding `-sysdir ~/development/app/test/android/` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by doing the following:

1. Move the config file and content directory to ~/development/app/test/android/.android/avd/, this will require modifying the 'path' value in the .ini file.
2. Define ANDROID_SDK_HOME in your environment to point to $HOME/development/app/test/android

When this variable is defined, the emulator will always look under $ANDROID_SDK_HOME/.android/avd/ for AVD configuration files.

Also a file like Test1.ini contains a line like:

```
path=/full/path/to/Test1.avd
```

Which gives the path to the AVD's content directory.

By default, the SDK's AVD Manager creates new AVD instances with a content path of $ANDROID_SDK_HOME/.android/avd/.avd but you can actually use a different location as long as your .ini file points to it.

The .ini file is always looked up under $ANDROID_SDK_HOME/.android/avd/ though.